# Center action bars title

Tags: java, android, xml

I have tried all of the answers given to my problem here on Stack Overflow, however none of them seemed to work on my project, I can't center the action bars title.
 How do I do that?

I have tried all of the answers that showed up here, none of them worked, here is the code.
(Ps: I have previously checked for any misspelling errors, although I didn't find any)

Code:

```
@Override protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) { 

super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); 
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main); 
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayOptions(ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_CUSTOM); 
getSupportActionBar().setCustomView(R.layout.abs_layout); 

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding this in your abs_layout xml file

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:orientation="vertical">


<android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView
    android:id="@+id/BarTitle"
    style="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Widget.ActionBar.Title"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
    android:text="Hello"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: I have, my abs_layout xml file looks exactly like that, however it doesn't work and my title disappeared.